# liferay 6.0.6 on glassfish 3.1.1 don't show all the text

Tags: glassfish, liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying to deploy Liferay 6.0.6 on a fresh Glassfish 3.1.1 installation in rhel 5.6 with java 1.7.01. I downloaded the liferay war, unzipped and copied the dependencies and sqljdbc4.jar to $GLASSFISH_HOME/domains/domain1/lib/, increased the Xmx to 1024m and the permgen to 512m, then i deploy the liferay-portal-6.0.6-20110225.war, don't show errors on deploy. When i open a browser, it don't show all the html or screw it.

I have another one working right, i copied all the domain folder, but that doesn't work, i tested with the bundle with glassfish 3.0.1 and it works great

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to clear the browser cache and reload page?

Comment: yes, i clear the cache and tried in explorer and in firefox

Comment: May by you use another port (8080 by default for domain1)? And after adding lib's is necessary to restart domain.